# What is the javac/java file system concurrency contract?

Tags: java, concurrency, javac

I'm running a multi-threaded build with two dependant com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile() invocations running on separate threads with ~10ms pause between them. Every now (every 100 builds or so), the second javac complains about bad class formats in the outputs from the  first javac.

This is on linux, but it has to work on all os'es. What are the constraints I'm facing here?

I'm working on a concurrent build system, so the reason I'm invoking the javacs is because they're in different modules. There is external synchronization that ensures the run-order (but I'm not actually inside a synchronized block when I invoke the compile() method), and I know for sure that they're being invoked one after the other, with approx 10-20ms pause on average. For all I can understand these two calls to compile() should really only be sharing the file system ?

Edit 2:
The thread invoking the second compile() call is in a wait() until the first one is finished, so there is order-synchronization. But I'm not inside a synchronized block when I invoke the actual call to compile. Compile is a static method, and I am assuming they don't have any internal safe-publication issues in that context...(?)

Edit 3: Synchronizing the call to compile() does not help. Neither does calling just sync() to linux. But I haven't looked into flushing buffers at the java level if possible.

Comment: why precisely are your doing that ? please add more details

Comment: If they are separate threads, without synchronization, how can you expect it'll always work? It's reasonable that once in a hundred times the first thread will be delayed at least 10ms. I think you need synchronization between the threads, or a greater delay between them.

Comment: If there is no internal synchronization and only a 10 or 20ms delay between the threads, it might be that the thread which is started last gets executed earlier due to the nature of scheduling. One in a hundred seems to back this theory up. This is why I argue you need real synchronization between the threads. If the second call to compile depends on something the first call should build, you can see bad class formats. I may still be making wrong assumptions. If I am, clarify your question further.

Comment: Perhaps the compiled classes are still idling in a buffer somewhere between OutputStream, C-Library-Caching, the Filesystem and the Linux Buffercache. How about force-closing the Streams and then somehow getting the VM to call sync() before starting the next compile.

Comment: edgar.holleis: That's actually a half-decent solution. I think this  should be an "answer" and not a comment. I'll give this a try run it for a few hundred builds or so ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the javac/java file system
>   concurrency contract ?

There isn't one. If you are compiling a class in thread A that is needed by another compiler in thread B, you shouldn't be. Simple as that.

Comment: According to the nice people at #kernel, linux guarantees visibility of all contents of a file at close() time. So if I fork a separate process I should be home free? Do you have any references to back up the "there isn't one" statement - I'm curious to read more...

Comment: You asked about the javac/java contract. If you can find one please let us know. In any case how can you possibly know that thread A will compile the class before thread B needs it?

Comment: Because I wait for thread A to finish before I even start thread B. That is, unless A forks more threads, which I wouldn't know

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. If you are running thread A and waiting for it to finish and then running thread B, why do they have to be threads? You could just essentially do a.run(); b.run() and save yourself all the starts and joins.

Comment: because thread a proceeds to run unit tests for classes in A immediately after finishing compile. same for b.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question.